# Understanding Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to understand the output of the following queries in Cypher.

```
start n=node:node_auto_index(name="root_node")
match n-[:SC]->c, b<-[:CB]-c-[:CB]->b1
where (b.days_in_number - b1.days_in_number <= 7) AND (b.days_in_number > b1.days_in_number)
and c.name = "C16659"
with  distinct n,c, b, b1
match  n-[:SC]->c-[:CB]->b-[:CT]->i1, n-[:SC]->c-[:CB]->b1-[:CT]->i2 
with b.name as bname,b1.name as b1name,i1.name as i1name,i2.name as i2name
return  bname,b1name,i1name,i2name
order by bname,b1name,i1name,i2name;
```

**returns 3680 rows**

```
start n=node:node_auto_index(name="root_node") 
match n-[:SC]->c, b<-[:CB]-c-[:CB]->b1
where (b.days_in_number - b1.days_in_number <= 7) AND (b.days_in_number > b1.days_in_number)
and c.name = "C16659"
with  distinct n,c, b, b1
match  b-[:CT]->i1, b1-[:CT]->i2 
with b.name as bname,b1.name as b1name,i1.name as i1name,i2.name as i2name
return  bname,b1name,i1name,i2name
order by bname,b1name,i1name,i2name;
```

**returns 184 rows**

query 1 seems to be doing cartesian, but I am unable to understand why? Can anyone please explain?

c-[:CB]->b is 1:n relationship.

UPDATE:

when I run the following query I get correct 184 results:

```
start n=node:node_auto_index(name="root_node") 
match n-[:SC]->c, b<-[:CB]-c-[:CB]->b1
where (b.days_in_number - b1.days_in_number <= 7) AND (b.days_in_number > b1.days_in_number)
and c.name = "C16659"
with  distinct n,c, b, b1
match  c-[:CB]->b-[:CT]->i1, c-[:CB]->b1-[:CT]->i2 
with n.name as nname,c.name as cname, b.name as bname,b1.name as b1name,i1.name as i1name,i2.name as i2name
return  nname,cname,bname,b1name,i1name,i2name
order by nname,cname,bname,b1name,i1name,i2name;
```

This suggests putting n back leads to Cartesian.

n-[:SC]->c is 1:1 relationship. Why is this happening?

Comment: Your distinct removes duplication in the first case, you can use return count(c), count(distinct c) (and also for n,b,b1) after the first query part to get some counts. Also note that different match patterns that don't belong together create a cartesian product.

Comment: At the end I went with not using "n" in the match clause. It does return correctly. I am unable to still understand why having n causes cartesian. I have only one root node "n" in the DB. Thanks for your comments. I checked distinct and it all looked as per expectation, just n was causing the cartesian, I believe we dont need to include n anyways if rest of the nodes are correctly bound.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that the relationship between n and c is realy unique? Maybee looking at the paths will help. Try

```
match p1=n-[:SC]->c-[:CB]->b-[:CT]->i1, p2=n-[:SC]->c-[:CB]->b1-[:CT]->i2
return p1,p2
```

to see where the aditional results differ from each other.